# What to substitute for array_agg in a PostgreSQL subquery when switching to Derby?

Tags: arrays, jdbc, subquery, concatenation, derby

I have a java application that for some installations acceses a PostgreSQL database, while in others it acceses essentially the same database in Derby.

I have a SQL query that returns an examination record from the examination table. There is an exam_procedure table that relates to the examination table in a one (examination) to many fashion. I need to concatenate the potentially multiple string records in the exam_procedure table so that I can add a single string value to the query return that represents all the related exam_procedure records. For a variety of reasons (eg, joins return too many records, especially when multiple subqueries are needed for other related one to many tables), I need to do this via a subquery in the SELECT section of the main query. The following SQL works just fine for PostgreSQL, but my understanding is that array_agg is not available in Derby. What Derby subquery can I substitute for the PostgreSQL subquery?

Many thanks.

```
// part of the query
        "SELECT "
            + "patient_id, "
            + "examination_date, "
            + "examination_number, "
            + "operating_physician_id, "
            + "referring_physician_id, "
            + "patient.last_name AS pt_last_name, "
            + "patient.first_name AS pt_first_name, "
            + "patient.middle_name AS pt_middle_name, "

            + "("
                + "SELECT "
                    + "array_agg(prose) "
                + "FROM "
                    + "exam_procedure "
                + "WHERE examination_id = " + examId
                + " GROUP BY examination_id"
            + ") AS agg_procedures, "

        + "FROM "
            + "examination "
        + "JOIN patient ON patient.id = examination.patient_id "
        + "WHERE "
            + "examination.id = ?"
    ;
```